# Spring Mongo: Repository do not return date in order

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-repositories

I am trying to get objects from Mongodb in ascending (or descending) timestamp order.

This is how the document looks like:

```
{
    _id: 5b01ffe3cd8b295aed16d5c0Wed
    temperature: 23
    timestamp: Dec 13 09:27:00 CET 2017
}
```

I am using Spring repository:

```
public interface TemperatureRepo extends MongoRepository<TemperatureObject, String> {
    public List<TemperatureObject> findAllByOrderByTimestampDesc();
}
```

But somehow, Desc and Asc queries never work. I always get the result set in same order (which is not ordered at all)

The attribute `temperature` is saved as `Date` not as `String`

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Show a document from MongoDB and not a console dump. Then we can see for certain what it is actually saved as. More to the point, show a few documents and the order you expect as well as the order they come out in.

Answer (score 1):

try this, it will solve your problem.

```
List<TemperatureObject> temperatureObjects = temperatureRepo.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "timestamp"));
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems to work. I need to test it though